# Facebook SDK install measures?

Tags: sdk, facebook

In the documentation, they tell you to use this code:

```
[FBSettings setDefaultAppID:YOUR_APP_ID];
[FBAppEvents activateApp];
```

To measure installs in your app, and you must do this to use CPA bidding. They state that:

`The first instance of activateApp will be treated as an install by Facebook. So, we recommend you add the code above for the latest iOS and Android SDKs to measure both installs and other app events.`

So basically if I were to run a CPA bid campaign with Facebook ads, anytime my app was installed, even if it wasn't from a facebook ad, it would be counted as an install and I would be charged for it?

If not, then why does facebook require me to integrate this code in the app if they don't actually need it to see when someone installs my app from their ad?

Answer (score 0):

No. That call is just to say that the app is started. Facebook will then look to see if that user clicked on a Facebook ad. Facebook need you to add it because otherwise there is no way for them to know if the app is installed.

Comment: Then can you explain to me why my current CPC campaign says "0 mobile app installs"? If facebook can track installs and report to me how many I am getting, why do they need this code?

Comment: I just say they can't track number installs without the code

Comment: I understand you said that, so you're telling me that it will say zero installs forever?